# How to give access to a single Bigquery Dataset for a user to access the data in Datalooker?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio, google-cloud-iam, identity-management

I am able to give access to a single dataset and access only that dataset in the console.

So it's a Bigquery Data Editor and he can create tables, run SQL's and so on.

[image]

But I need for this user to also have access only to this Dataset using DataLooker:

What I tried:

- giving bigquery user access to the project (but then it has access to all dataset)
- I tried filtering this access by dataset using IAM condition but doesn't work.
- not having access as Bigquery User he can't see the project in datalooker
  [image]

### Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign roles at two different levels:

1. [Assign the BigQuery Data Editor role at the Dataset level](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/control-access-to-resources-iam#grant_access_to_a_dataset)

> When applied to a dataset, this role provides permissions to:
>
> Read the dataset's metadata and list tables in the dataset. Create,
> update, get, and delete the dataset's tables.

[image]

2. At the project level you need to assign some role with the `resourcemanager.projects.list` and `resourcemanager.projects.get` permission I recommend the [Browser role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#browser)

> Read access to browse the hierarchy for a project, including the folder, organization, and allow policy. This role doesn't include permission to view resources in the project.

Comment: seems to work, but not able to fetch data. So it gets all metadata of the tables, but not the data within the reports...

Comment: If you want to run  queries and jobs you should add the BigQuery Job User role at the project level. If you do that you could replace the role Browser